# Can I use MiGLayout with C++?

Tags: c++, layout, miglayout, layout-manager

I wonder if there is a C++ port if [MiGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) or if there is a way that I can use MiGLayout with C++.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if miglayout has a port to C++, but [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) has decent layout tools. If you don't find good tools, maybe you can consider Qt as an option?

Also, you can use Qt in many languages other than C++.